# Using FFMpeg as a Directshow Source Filter

Tags: ffmpeg, directshow

Is it possible to use ffmpeg as a directshow source filter?
Specially, Can i read live stream via ffmpeg and then send it's output to directshow graph?

Comment: ffdshow tryouts "might" have an avs input, FWIW

Comment: Could you, tell me more descrptions about that?, Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know much about it except I saw it in an ffdshow tryouts dialog box once [it might have been just a pass through filter anyway unfortunately...]

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use FFmpeg via command line then the answer is "No". You cannot send its output to DirectShow filter graph because the data pipelines are in different processes and you are supposed to somehow connect the two together.

However if you use libav* libraries of FFmpeg and wrap them into DirectShow source filter (similar to Push Source sample), this can work.

Comment: Could you please tell me, How can i using labiv libraries as DS filter and read a live stream with it?

Comment: Use PushSource SDK sample (alternatively - VCam project from internet) as a base for your project. Add internal code that generates content using libav samples that control acquiring data from network source.

Comment: Many thanks, i couldn't found any samples for network source. where i can find libav-api network source sample code?